# What is the difference between a discrete and continuous rolling window?

Tags: moving-window

What I have read so far suggests that a discrete rolling window is say a yearly window, calculating somethig every year, which is from 01-01/31-12 and a continuous rolling window is a window that moves along the time line.
So the continuous rolling window moves with a certain step (hour, day, week, month), meaning it extends the window by the step, whereby the 'back' of the window is cut down by this step, essentially dropping the last step that belongs to a certain window.

Is that correct or what does the distinction mean?

Comment: I think you mean sliding and tumbling windows. You can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602368/sliding-vs-tumbling-windows

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for.